# как выровнять блоки сайта ровно?

Tags: bootstrap

Верстаю сайт, в целях самообучения и столкнулся с проблемой, что не пойму как выровнять последний блок, так чтобы он начинался с той же точки как и первый?
    Конечно понимаю, что можно использовать margin-left: 7%; но есть ли еще какой-либо способ?

Не пойму как выровнять последний блок, так чтобы он начинался с той же точки как и первый.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="logo">
                            Elena
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="name">
                        <h1>HAVE A GOOD DAY</h1>
                        <p>JUST FOR YOU ON THEMEFOREST</p>
                    </div>
                    <form action="" class="form">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-get">
                            <a href="#">GET YOUR COPY NOW</a>
                        </button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="present" id="present">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="present-menu">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="block-menu">
                                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                <h4>Proffesionals</h4>
                                <div class="line-first"></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="block-menu">
                                <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                                <h4>Amateurs</h4>
                                <div class="line-first"></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="block-menu">
                                <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
                                <h4>For Everyone</h4>
                                <div class="line-first"></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="read" id="read">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="readmore d-flex">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="read-block">
                                <img src="img/Layer 14.png" alt="">
                                <h4>Responsive email template</h4>
                                <div class="line-two"></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br> adipiscing elit. Donec interdum mollis</p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-read">
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="read-block">
                                <img src="img/Layer 16.png" alt="">
                                <h4>Fully compatible template</h4>
                                <div class="line-two"></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br> adipiscing elit. Donec interdum mollis</p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-read">
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="supported" id="supported">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="support-block">
                        <h3><i class="far fa-life-ring"></i>Fully Supported template</h3>
                        <div class="line-tree"></div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada sodales risus, a <br> adipiscing lorem commodo vitae. Ut semper semper lacus. Suspendisse convallis vel tellus at <br> consectetur. Aenean risus arcu</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-support">
                                <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Конечно понимаю, что можно использовать margin-left: 7%; но есть ли еще какой-либо способ?

Comment: Поместите его в блок `container`

Comment: так он и так в блоке container)

Comment: Тогда сделайте полный пример [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Каждому блоку с `col-` классом задается `padding` и если вы вкладываете `col-` елемент в 
`col-` без обертки `row` отступы сумируются, что и вызывает смещение.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="present" id="present">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row present-menu">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-menu">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <h4>Proffesionals</h4>
          <div class="line-first"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-menu">
          <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
          <h4>Amateurs</h4>
          <div class="line-first"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-menu">
          <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt"></i>
          <h4>For Everyone</h4>
          <div class="line-first"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur elit. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="read" id="read">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row readmore d-flex">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="read-block">
          <img src="img/Layer 14.png" alt="">
          <h4>Responsive email template</h4>
          <div class="line-two"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br> adipiscing elit. Donec interdum mollis</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-read">
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="read-block">
          <img src="img/Layer 16.png" alt="">
          <h4>Fully compatible template</h4>
          <div class="line-two"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br> adipiscing elit. Donec interdum mollis</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-read">
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="supported" id="supported">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="support-block">
          <h3><i class="far fa-life-ring"></i>Fully Supported template</h3>
          <div class="line-tree"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada sodales risus, a <br> adipiscing lorem commodo vitae. Ut semper semper lacus. Suspendisse convallis vel tellus at <br> consectetur. Aenean risus arcu</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-support">
                                <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```